# How to fix data length error in postgresql and django

Tags: postgresql, django-rest-framework

The project is in django and works pretty well with SQLite but when migrate to PostgreSQL and try to register a user shows this error

```
File "C:\Users\liz\developer\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.DataError: the value is too long for varchar type varying(30)
```

Already change the slug fields to 255 but error still there

Comment: Unless you have specific reasons for limiting the length there is no reason to do so. Just define you column as `character varying` (no length specified) or `text`.  In Postgres there is no advantage in specifying a length. Seems like your length is greater than 255.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers say that must change the slugfields to 255, I looking for in vscode for the max_length=30 and I found a couple of fields with that length, I change all the fields to 255 and it worked, if you ever face this change all the fields in all models to 255  to make it works and then modify as you need